# If Exists inside a CTE in SQl Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I just want to know that How to write a `CTE` containing `If Exists` in SQl Server ?
I had tried to write a CTE below where i am Using `If Exists` Statement to select weather the record exist or not .In case if the record does not exist then i am assigning default value but i am getting error

> 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'if'

.' Please help me to fix this error and guide me to write this CTE.
Please find below the CTE which i had written:-

```
Alter procedure St_Proc_GetTeamProductionReport      
@mindate DateTime,                        
@maxdate DateTIme,    
@userID varchar(50)                    
as                                          
Begin                                          
     set NoCount on; 
with    
ProductionCTE(CalendarDate,RoleID,UserID,UserECode,UserName,ImmediateSupervisor,NatureOfWorkName,RegionProjectName,CountyName,WorkTypeName,TaskName,VolumneProcessed,TimeSpent,Comment)    
as    
(    
    if exists
    (
        select P.CalendarDate,U.RoleID,U.UserID,U.UserECode,U.UserName,U.ImmediateSupervisor,N.NatureofWorkName,    
        R.RegionProjectName,C.Countyname,W.WorktypeName,T.TaskName,P.VolumeProcessed,P.Timespent,P.Comment    
        from production P inner join NatureOfWork N    
        on N.NatureofWorkID=P.natureofworkid    
        inner join dbo.RegionAndProjectInfo R    
        on R.RegionProjectID=P.RegionProjectID    
        inner join county C    
        on C.countyid=P.countyid    
        inner join worktype W    
        on W.Worktypeid=P.worktypeID    
        inner join task T    
        on T.taskid=P.TaskID    
        inner join UserInfo U    
        on U.Userid=P.userid    
        where P.userid=@userID  and ( convert(varchar, P.CalendarDate, 101) )  between (
        convert(varchar, @mindate, 101) ) and ( convert(varchar, @maxdate, 101) )  
    )
    else
    (
        Select '2012-09-14 13:41:52' as CalendarDate,
        2 as RoleID,'938' as UserID,
        (select Userecode from Userinfo where userid=@userID) as UserECode,
        (select UserName from Userinfo where userid=@userID)as UserName,
        (select ImmediateSupervisor from Userinfo where userid=@userID)as ImmediateSupervisor,
        'BP' as NatureOfWorkName,
        'CO Processing' as RegionProjectName,
        'Adams' as CountyName,
        'Quality' as WorkTypeName,
        'Corrections ' as TaskName,
        5 as VolumneProcessed,
        '01:00' as TimeSpent,
        'test' as Comment
        ) 

    union all

    select P.CalendarDate,U.RoleID,U.UserID,U.UserECode,U.UserName,U.ImmediateSupervisor,N.NatureofWorkName,    
    R.RegionProjectName,C.Countyname,W.WorktypeName,T.TaskName,P.VolumeProcessed,P.Timespent,P.Comment    
    from production P inner join NatureOfWork N    
    on N.NatureofWorkID=P.natureofworkid    
    inner join dbo.RegionAndProjectInfo R    
    on R.RegionProjectID=P.RegionProjectID    
    inner join county C    
    on C.countyid=P.countyid    
    inner join worktype W    
    on W.Worktypeid=P.worktypeID    
    inner join task T    
    on T.taskid=P.TaskID    
    inner join UserInfo U    
    on U.Userid=P.userid    
    inner join ProductionCTE    
    on U.ImmediateSupervisor=ProductionCTE.UserECode    

    where P.IsTaskCompleted=1   and ( convert(varchar, P.CalendarDate, 101) )  between (
    convert(varchar, @mindate, 101) ) and ( convert(varchar, @maxdate, 101) )         
)  
select  distinct CONVERT(VARCHAR,CalendarDate,20) as CalendarDate,UserECode,UserName,NatureOfWorkName,RegionProjectName,CountyName,WorkTypeName,TaskName,VolumneProcessed,TimeSpent,Comment from ProductionCTE where  RoleID=1    
end
```

GO

When i am removing this If Exist statement then the `CTE` is working fine but after adding the `IF Exists` statement it is having error.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `IF EXISTS` in this way. A common table expression must only contain a single select statement, it's not possible to say `if condition SELECT THIS else SELECT THAT`.

It looks like you are trying to add an additional created row to a resultset returned by a query. You could achieve this by implementing the CTE as a table-valued function that would return the single new row.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms191165(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you want to construct a `UNION` where you only get a result from the second `SELECT` if the first `SELECT` returns no rows, you can achieve this using `RANK()`. So, you can place your real query in the first `SELECT` and the desired default values in the second, and achieve the results you want.

I don't have your tables and data, so I'm not going to attempt to re-write your query. But I'll illustrate with this:

```
;With WithDefaults as (
    select name,0 as Rank from sys.objects
    union all
    select 'abc',1 --Default if no results
), Ranked as (
    select *,RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Rank) as Rnk from WithDefaults
)
select * from Ranked where Rnk = 1
```

Returns (on a mostly empty DB I tried it on) 98 results, of which none had the `name` `abc`. If we force the first `SELECT` to return no results:

```
    select name,0 as Rank from sys.objects where 1 = 2
```

We now get a single row result with the `name` `abc`.

Hopefully, you can see how this could apply to your original query.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use IF EXISTS in CTE. But you can modify logic of function

Example:

```
alter procedure St_Proc_GetTeamProductionReport
@mindate DateTime,                        
@maxdate DateTIme,    
@userID varchar(50)                    
as                                          
Begin                                          
set NoCount on;
;with    
ProductionCTE(CalendarDate,RoleID,UserID,UserECode,UserName,ImmediateSupervisor,NatureOfWorkName,RegionProjectName,CountyName,WorkTypeName,TaskName,VolumneProcessed,TimeSpent,Comment)    
as    
(               
        select P.CalendarDate,U.RoleID,U.UserID,U.UserECode,U.UserName,U.ImmediateSupervisor,N.NatureofWorkName,    
        R.RegionProjectName,C.Countyname,W.WorktypeName,T.TaskName,P.VolumeProcessed,P.Timespent,P.Comment, 1 AS cnt 
        from production P inner join NatureOfWork N    
        on N.NatureofWorkID=P.natureofworkid    
        inner join dbo.RegionAndProjectInfo R    
        on R.RegionProjectID=P.RegionProjectID    
        inner join county C    
        on C.countyid=P.countyid    
        inner join worktype W    
        on W.Worktypeid=P.worktypeID    
        inner join task T    
        on T.taskid=P.TaskID    
        inner join UserInfo U    
        on U.Userid=P.userid    
        where P.userid=@userID  and ( convert(varchar, P.CalendarDate, 101) )  between (
        convert(varchar, @mindate, 101) ) and ( convert(varchar, @maxdate, 101) )  
        UNION ALL
        Select '2012-09-14 13:41:52' as CalendarDate,
        2 as RoleID,'938' as UserID,
        (select Userecode from Userinfo where userid=@userID) as UserECode,
        (select UserName from Userinfo where userid=@userID)as UserName,
        (select ImmediateSupervisor from Userinfo where userid=@userID)as ImmediateSupervisor,
        'BP' as NatureOfWorkName,
        'CO Processing' as RegionProjectName,
        'Adams' as CountyName,
        'Quality' as WorkTypeName,
        'Corrections ' as TaskName,
        5 as VolumneProcessed,
        '01:00' as TimeSpent,
        'test' as Comment, 0 
     ), ProductionCTE2 AS    
    (    
    SELECT TOP(SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE COUNT(*) END FROM ProductionCTE WHERE cnt = 1)
           CalendarDate,RoleID,UserID,UserECode,UserName,ImmediateSupervisor,NatureofWorkName,    
           RegionProjectName,Countyname,WorktypeName,TaskName,VolumeProcessed,Timespent,Comment
    FROM ProductionCTE2           
    union all
    select P.CalendarDate,U.RoleID,U.UserID,U.UserECode,U.UserName,U.ImmediateSupervisor,N.NatureofWorkName,    
    R.RegionProjectName,C.Countyname,W.WorktypeName,T.TaskName,P.VolumeProcessed,P.Timespent,P.Comment    
    from production P inner join NatureOfWork N    
    on N.NatureofWorkID=P.natureofworkid    
    inner join dbo.RegionAndProjectInfo R    
    on R.RegionProjectID=P.RegionProjectID    
    inner join county C    
    on C.countyid=P.countyid    
    inner join worktype W    
    on W.Worktypeid=P.worktypeID    
    inner join task T    
    on T.taskid=P.TaskID    
    inner join UserInfo U    
    on U.Userid=P.userid    
    inner join ProductionCTE    
    on U.ImmediateSupervisor=ProductionCTE.UserECode
    where P.IsTaskCompleted=1   and ( convert(varchar, P.CalendarDate, 101) )  between (
    convert(varchar, @mindate, 101) ) and ( convert(varchar, @maxdate, 101) )         
)  
select  distinct CONVERT(VARCHAR,CalendarDate,20) as CalendarDate,UserECode,UserName,NatureOfWorkName,RegionProjectName,CountyName,WorkTypeName,TaskName,VolumneProcessed,TimeSpent,Comment 
from ProductionCTE2
where  RoleID=1    
end
```